# Excel/VBA - worksheet change event copy/paste/clear data

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to VBA and I was trying to automate a daily routine we do using excel. Basically I just want to copy raw data from a tool we have then paste this to excel. What the macro does is to process the data, put it in a table and generate a summary which will then be used for our reports. To do this, I have the following code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim processDB As Integer
Dim xWs As Worksheet
Dim xTable As PivotTable
If Not Application.Intersect(Range("A:D"), Target) Is Nothing Then
    processDB = MsgBox("Raw data has been changed. Do you want to accept the changes?", vbOKCancel)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If processDB = 2 Then
        Application.Undo
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    For Each xWs In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each xTable In xWs.PivotTables
            xTable.RefreshTable
        Next
    Next
ndata = Sheet3.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
Sheet3.Range("A" & ndata & ":" & "D" & ndata).Value = Sheet2.Range("B6:E6").Value
End If
End Sub
```

Problem is when the old data is larger than the new one. Let's say old = A1:D10 then new = A1:D5 so A6:D10 should be cleared. I need to somehow clear the values below the newly pasted table before processing. I was thinking of using global variables to record the last value of the rows then work with that but I'm not sure if there's another way to do this.

I copy the raw data from another application then paste it in sheet1... when the code detects a change it'll just update the pivot on sheet 2 and will record the summary for that day on sheet 3. The problem I have is when I paste a smaller data range.

```
OLD
AAA BBB CCC DDD
11  12  13  14
12  13  14  15

NEW
AAA BBB CCC DDD
33  36  39  44

Result
AAA BBB CCC DDD
33  36  39  44
12  13  14  15 <<< need this cleared somehow when I paste the new data
```

Any help is greatly appreciated and sorry for the newbie question :(

Comment: what defines old / new range in terms of your code? does it relate to `Sheet3` or `Sheet2`? When does it get copied in? Is the `Worksheet_Change` event triggered from the copy? As a side note, `ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll` will refresh all your pivots at once without having to loop the sheets and tables.*(note - this will also refresh data connections if you have any, which you may not want to do)*

Comment: @scott I've updated the post... thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Target` argument of the `Worksheet_Change` Event to determine how many rows were pasted in and compare that against any additional rows that still exist and delete any additional rows that are there.

I have fleshed that out in the code below and tested it. I also refactored your code in some ways that I thought made sense based on your question. I also put plenty of comments in the code to explain myself. Please ignore anything I may have misunderstood and apologies if I stepped on your code, too much :)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Application.Intersect(Range("A:D"), Target) Is Nothing Then

    'confirm changes
    Dim processDB As Integer

    processDB = MsgBox("Raw data has been changed. Do you want to accept the changes?", vbOKCancel)

    If processDB = 2 Then

        With Application
            .EnableEvents = False
            .Undo
            .EnableEvents = True
        End With

        Exit Sub 'put this because do you really need to update pivot tables and other data if there is no change?

    End If

    'clear out old data
    Dim lRowsRange As Long, lRowsTotal As Long
    lRows = Target.Rows.Count 'get row count of newly pasted range
    lRowsTotal = Me.Range("A" & Me.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'get row count of all data on sheet

    If lRowsTotal > lRows Then

        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Me.Range(Rows(lRowsTotal), Rows(lRows + 1)).Delete 'if total rows of data is more than paste range, delete extra rows
        Application.EnableEvents = True

    End If

    'refresh pivot tables
    ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll

    'Dim xWs As Worksheet, xTable As PivotTable
    'For Each xWs In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    '    For Each xTable In xWs.PivotTables
    '        xTable.RefreshTable
    '    Next
    'Next

    ndata = Sheet3.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    Sheet3.Range("A" & ndata & ":" & "D" & ndata).Value = Sheet2.Range("B6:E6").Value

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: @rookie17768 - glad it works and glad I could help. Please mark as answered if has indeed solved your question :)

Comment: No worries Scott... for a newbie, its always good to see what improvements can be done to make the code readable and efficient.

I've tested the code and it works when I paste the new data. Now I tried to delete the bottom row then accept the change but it deleted all the data... I'll try to find a solution for that or just make sure to always paste the data. Thanks again :)

Comment: ah ... good find to break the code! ... that is **very** important with `Worksheet_Change` event code, because so **many** things can trigger it. One thing you could to avoid when you delete entire rows would be to add this to the initial `If` block ... `And Me.Columns.Count <> Target.Columns.Count` ... But that will not work if you just delete a few columns from the row... so you'll have to be crafty as you consider all possible things that can happen.

Comment: Got that Scott... I was looking into adding conditions on the if statements to address the issue... even tried to step into the code to check the values I was getting (should've chosen this field... I love talking to myself when something's wrong with the logic hahaha)

Comment: `If Application.Intersect(Range("A1"), Target) Is Nothing` solved it :)